# Add cut/copy/paste on right button mouse click in Python's open file dialogue

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

In Python 3.7, I have some code to an openfile dialogue. In fact it is as simple as calling `askopenfilename(options)` function from tkinter.filedialog.py Now I would like to be able to use a cut/copy/paste menu on the entry field labeled File Name of the dialogue. Usually, you can type in a filename, or you can use Ctrl-C or Ctrl-V, but I want a right-mouse click cut/copy/paste menu as well.

I already have some code that accomplishes this fact.

```
class App(Tk):
    def make_textmenu(self):
        self.the_menu = Menu(self, tearoff=0)
        self.the_menu.add_command(label="Cut")
        self.the_menu.add_command(label="Copy")
        self.the_menu.add_command(label="Paste")
        self.the_menu.add_separator()
        self.the_menu.add_command(label="Select all")

    def callback_select_all(self, event):
        # select text after 50ms
        self.after(50, lambda:event.widget.select_range(0, 'end'))

    def show_textmenu(self, event):
        e_widget = event.widget
        self.the_menu.entryconfigure("Cut",command=lambda: e_widget.event_generate("<<Cut>>"))
        self.the_menu.entryconfigure("Copy",command=lambda: e_widget.event_generate("<<Copy>>"))
        self.the_menu.entryconfigure("Paste",command=lambda: e_widget.event_generate("<<Paste>>"))
        self.the_menu.entryconfigure("Select all",command=lambda: e_widget.select_range(0, 'end'))
        self.the_menu.tk.call("tk_popup", self.the_menu, event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # configure the root window
        self.make_textmenu()
        self.bind_class("Entry", "<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.show_textmenu)
        self.bind_class("Entry", "<Control-a>", self.callback_select_all)
        self.bind_class("Text", "<Button-3><ButtonRelease-3>", self.show_textmenu)
        self.bind_class("Text", "<Control-a>", self.callback_select_all)
```

When I put this code in a new main function of Tkinter filedialog.py and instead of its regular `test()` function I called:

```
fd = LoadFileDialog(self)
fd.go()
```

I do get an openfile dialog with the cut/copy/paste menu.

The problem is that I don't like how this dialog looks. I want the openfile dialog that I get with the askopenfilename function. But that one is not altered by my cut/copy/paste code.
`askopenfilename()` calls `Open(**options).show()`, and that results via the classes `_Dialog` and `commondialog.Dialog`, in the call

```
(with command: "tk_getOpenFile"):
    def show(self, **options):

        # update instance options
        for k, v in options.items():
            self.options[k] = v

        self._fixoptions()

        # we need a dummy widget to properly process the options
        # (at least as long as we use Tkinter 1.63)
        w = Frame(self.master)

        try:

            s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))

            s = self._fixresult(w, s)

        finally:

            try:
                # get rid of the widget
                w.destroy()
            except:
                pass

        return s
```

At this point I am lost. Where should I go and see how the call continues `(w.tk.call)`.